# Return the count of all prime numbers in range [a,b] such that all the digits are from set {1,5,9} . 1<=a<=b<=10⁹

Tags: performance, primes, bitmask

Return the count of all prime numbers in range [a,b] such that all the digits are from set {1,5,9} . 1<=a<=b<=10⁹.

My approach -
I was trying to generate all the numbers which are from set {1,5,9}. which comes out to be 3^9(19683) and after that I am checking for is it prime or not.

Can I do this in a better time complexity?

Comment: Except for 5 itself, no prime number can end in 5.  That greatly reduces the number of combinations you have to look at.

Comment: 3^9 is only the count of the integers that have *exactly* nine digits from {1,5,9}. It doesn't include 8 digit integers, 7 digit, etc.

Comment: One cannot measure complexity without an algorithm, and you haven't really provided any significant details to perform such an analysis. You've suggested how you'd generate the set, but not with much detail, and you haven't mentioned at all how you'd check for primality.

Comment: Two approaches come to my mind immediately: 1) find all primes up to 10^9 using a sieve, then generate each candidate and perform a lookup to see if it's prime, or 2) generate each candidate and use a deterministic Miller-Rabin test (using bases 2, 7, and 61 for example) to see if it is prime. I'd guess #1 is faster but I'm not sure.

Comment: @PresidentJamesK.Polk First of all, we can't use sieve here because the time complexity of sieve is O(nloglogn) and it works for up to 10^7  and I guess the same goes for 2nd approach.

Comment: It's a big sieve, that's true. If I get a chance I'll try both, but you need some way to test for primality. What's your proposal?

Comment: I implemented both techniques in python+numpy+sympy, and method 1) took about 5 seconds but method 2 took only .06 seconds. Method 2 was the clear winner.

Comment: @PresidentJamesK.Polk the number of all {1,5,9} 9-or-less digits numbers is less than 20,000, and the number of primes below 10^9 as on the order of 50 million, so it makes sense. (curiously, `sum [3^k*2 | k <-[0..8]]` == `3^9-1` == 19682). there are so few of them, maybe even the simple trial division test will be fast enough.

Answer (score 0):

1. Never generate a large set and *after* check all elements of the set, ruling out most. That requires a lot of memory to store things you'll be discarding. Instead, find a single number with "valid" digits, check for primeness, and *only then* store it in a set. Accessing large arrays of memory is very time-intense on modern computers compared to doing math.
2. "I produced all the numbers": I hope you're doing this smartly! You never have to check a number with a last digit being 5 for primeness (there's only a single prime that ends in 5; that's 5 itself!), for example. Also, you hopefully don't just build all combinations of digits "manually". Say, you find a number 1955**1**, then 1955**9** is also a candidate, you never have to manually "combine" digits to try out the last digit.
3. Of course, your prime-checking algorithm needs to be matching your kind of problem: You can remove the initial check for divisibility by 2 (you never produce even numbers), for example. You never need to check for divisibility by 5, because you never use 5 or 0 as last digit. Depending on your prime checking algorithm, you also would want to save the factor that "killed" the xxxx1 – that's one factor you don't have to check xxxx9 against. Do your 3-factor-checking based on the count of 1,5 and 9 in your number; you can directly infer cross-sum and hence 3-divisibility from that.